# MacBookPro 13" not install Intel HAXM accelerator for android emulators via ruboto

Tags: android, jruby, installation, ruboto, haxm

After [installed](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/blob/master/README.md) ruboto gem and properly dependencies (via Gemfile), i typed:

```
$ ruboto setup
```

Which returns to me a error and properly download; but after download and installed the error package, the command returns same package error:

```
Java runtime             : Found
Java Compiler            : Found
Apache ANT               : Found
Android Package Installer: Found
Android Emulator         : Found
Intel HAXM               : Not found
Android SDK Command adb  : Found
Android SDK Command dx   : Found
Platform SDK android-15  : Found

!!! Ruboto setup is NOT OK !!!

Android tools not found.
Would you like to download and install them? (Y/n): Y
Refresh Sources:
...
...
...
Installing Archives:
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.3
Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.3
  Installed Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.399%)
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1
  Stopping ADB server succeeded.
  Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.199%)
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
Installing Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
  Installed Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.399%)
Downloading Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 4
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 4
  Installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 499%)
  Stopping ADB server succeeded.
  Starting ADB server succeeded.
  null  Done. 4 packages installed.
  Android SDK Command dx   : Found
  Android SDK Command adb  : Found
  Android Emulator         : Found
  Intel HAXM               : Not found
  Java runtime             : Found
  Java Compiler            : Found
  Apache ANT               : Found
  Android Package Installer: Found
  Android Emulator         : Found
  Intel HAXM               : Not found
  Android SDK Command adb  : Found
  Android SDK Command dx   : Found
  Platform SDK android-15  : Found

  !!! Ruboto setup is NOT OK !!!
```

Why such thing happens? HAXM already installed? maybe i need setup PATH in ~/.bash_profile?
By the way, above is part of my .bash_profile

```
  # BEGIN Android
  export A_HOME=$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/
  export A_TOOLS=$HOME/Development/tools
  export AP_TOOLS=$A_TOOLS:$HOME/Development/platform-tools
  export AB_TOOLS=$AP_TOOLS:$HOME/Development/build-tools
  # END Android

  # BEGIN Ruboto setup
  source ~/.rubotorc
  # END Ruboto setup
```

Comment: Here is a [troubleshooting blog for HAXM][1].  Can you verify that HAXM is running on your system and that you have the most recent version?  

Do you have Virtualbox running on your system?  If you have a program running on your system that is using the VT resources, HAXM will not work and you will get errors. 


  [1]: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm

Comment: @chileAddict Now works; the problem was solved in this manner: i reboot computer, opened ADT package installers, updated SDK and ADT and now works :P

Comment: I'm glad that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel HAXM you have installed in the Android SDK manager only copies the Intel HAXM executable on your machine. You have to install Intel HAXM manually.

Look for the installation dmg in `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_[version].dmg`

source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213269